# How to make %LIKE% search in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, ubercart

I got Drupal 7 and ubercart installed.  I'm using standart shaerch engine. How can i search in my store using queries like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE product_desc LIKE %search_word%`

What files i need to change to search with part-words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core search module only does exact match search. You could try the [Porter-Stemmer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) to get the "LIKE" search if your site is English language only.

A more flexible approach would be to use the Views module and create a search form that is for your products. Performance would be better and you could easily extend the functionality in the future.